# How to get more information about Microsoft C++ exception

Tags: ida

I am running a very old app written in VB6 and working with crystal reports.
The apps worked great but since last windows 10 update, the crystal reports returns me an error. I debugged the app with IDA and i see this exception:

```
 751804C2: Microsoft C++ exception (etc.code e06d7363, tid 2680)
```

This exception is only shown when debugging with IDA. If i launch the app manually, i just get a crystal reports error.

What should i do in order to get more informations about this exception ?
I tried to run program step by step in IDA: I just see this exception fired in kernelBase.dll, but i don't really know if exception is raising in this module or if this module just catch the exception...

Thanks